# Values of variable not saving Swiftui

Tags: swift, variables, swiftui

I am working on a swiftui app where I am getting the sign in data from the user when they login. But for some reason the data that I save to the variable is just not saving. The data get pulled from the api and when the Post function is running the data is there but as soon as the function finishes the data gets turned to nil.

```
@Published var userData : SignInData?
@Published var signInSuccess: Bool = false

func signIn(bodyData:Any, completion: @escaping((Error?, SignInData?) -> Void)) { /
        if let url = URL(string: signInURL) {
            let session = URLSession.shared

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyData)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(SignInData.self, from: safeData)

                            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                                //print(results)
                                self.userData = results
                                completion(nil,results)
                                self.signInSuccess = true
                            }

                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                            completion(error,nil)

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    struct SignInData: Codable{
    var Message : String?
    var UID : String?
    var Dob : String?
    var FirstName : String?
    var LastName : String?
    var UserName : String?
    var Status:String?
    var Rank : String?
    var Cell : String?
    var Insider : String?
    var Interests : String?
    var Gender : String?
    var Location : String?
    var ParentsStatus : String?
    var School : String?
    var FB_username: String?
    var FB_score : String?
    var IG_username : String?
    var IG_score : String?
    var TW_username : String?
    var Tw_score : String?
    var Email: String?
    var Balance : String?
}
```

This is where I call it in another Class

```
@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

if self.networkManager.userData?.Status == "0"{
     print("the account is not activated yet")
}
else{
     print("successful")
}
```

Comment: It looks like the reason is out of provided code.